# Including date and time in Tex File

Tags: shell, latex, debian, pdflatex

The latex file is giving the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `datetime.sty' not found.
```

Here is the Latex code: `\usepackage{datetime}`

Am I missing something?

I am using Debian 3.1 Linux Machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your LaTeX Distribution does not load the package automatically, you can try to install it manually according to the readme file here: <del>http://www.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/datetime/</del> *Edit:* http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime

Comment: Fine! I wonder though why the package was not retrieved automatically. On the other hand Deb. 3.1 is not the newsest OS... :D

Comment: LaTeX contains hundreds of styles, extensions and so on. All common Unix-distributions split it into basic always needed packages and optional packages. The optional packages have to be installed separately.

Comment: @Mnementh Thanks for the infos. I was not aware of this rather monolithic behavior of  teTex and Co. My MikTex distribution on Windows is smart enough to have a package manager that autoloads reqired packages from a repository once they are called by \usepackage{}. I thought this was as often just a copied Unix-ish behavior but apparently I was wrong... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I don't use Debian myself, but if I look it up, Debian contains it in the package 'texlive-latex-extra'. If you installed LaTeX via the packet-manager of debian (I think so) the command 'apt-get install texlive-latex-extra' executed as root should install you the needed file. Alternatively you can use a graphical package-manager to install the package.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are missing the *datetime.sty* file; you are probably missing the whole package too.  What system are you using for managing your (La)TeX installation ?  If you tell us you may get more specific advice than I can give.

You need to get the datetime package from CTAN or one of its mirrors and install it into your local texmf tree.  Your LaTeX manager will do this for you.  You may also be able to configure your LaTeX manager to automatically download and install packages the first time they are requested.